# Is JSON format suitable for a custom HTTP Header?

Tags: json, http, rest

It's useful to add custom HTTP header to provide application specific metadata or information to client, and hoping one day it can be a standard like link header (Web Linking).

Most of HTTP headers are designed under RFC 2616 specification with char, : | < | > | ; | = | " | ' |, etc. It's more close to human readable string than machine readable (easy to parse or not).

Now, I want to add a custom HTTP header to contain a structure information, which is easy to represent in object format like JSON object. Is it OK to add a custom HTTP header which it's value is a serialized JSON object or I should follow the convention to reformat it into some kind format like link header?

Hoping you guys can provide some advices on this, or other best practices to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You can always Base 64 encode the header value. Make sure your header name starts with `X-`.

Comment: How does prefixing with "X-" affects things?

Comment: The `X-` prefix is obsolete for quite some time. There is no need for anymore.

Comment: 1. the "X-" prefixing rule of private HTTP header is deprecated to gain backward compatibility when this header becomes a standard one.   2. I think Base 64 encoding is used only it's necessary to remain the readability, but thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need JSON, use JSON. Be sure to get non-ASCII characters right, though.

Comment: Correct, you can rely here on URI encoding. This is a safe bet.

Comment: Michael-O: URI encoding is total overkill for that. Just make sure to generate a pure ASCII JSON serialization.

Comment: No, it's. Only non-ASCII chars will be encoded. Otherwise you won't have Unicode at all.

Comment: Michael-O: URI encoding changes also ASCII-characters, such as "&", "<" and ">". There's no point in doing so in a header field value.

Comment: At least, it makes the entire value ASCII-safe.

Comment: Michael-O: it does, but it's a big hammer. JSON has escapes for this, so there's absolute no reason to apply yet another encoding to it.

Comment: You won't save anything plus `\r` and `\n` won't be properly escaped.

Comment: It saves one layer of encoding, and it does also save bytes on the wire. And yes, controls such as \r and \n will need to be escaped as well.

Comment: thanks! I think if there are non-ASCII chars, I should encode them before serializing into JSON serialization, not encoding the header value.

Comment: But I want to make sure that this option (using JSON) is just OK or a common way to do that? Maybe this idea will hard to be accepted by some one they design the standard HTTP headers. But I hope not.

Comment: Jack Yu - if you are concerned about the format, the best way to collect feedback is to post to the IETF HTTPbis mailing list (see http://tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/wiki#Participate for details)